# Magento 2 - store media in module folder and access it in template

Tags: magento2, module

My extension comes with an icon, where can I place it in my module and how can I load it in the modules template?

Template:

```
<img src="/media/icons/new-badge.svg" class="new-icon" alt="NEW">
```

Comment: where it is placed at the moment ?

Comment: In app/code/VENDOR/MODULE

Comment: you can put at `app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/web/images`

Comment: And how can I access it from the template?

Comment: You can access it by : `<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('VENDOR_MODULE::images/icon.png'); ?>">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put icon/images at:

> app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/web/images

to access those image in template, You can use:

```
 <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('VENDOR_MODULE::images/icon.png'); ?>">
```

Hope above will help!